# 'ColumnTransformer' object has no attribute 'get_feature_names_out' ( I am getting this error after implementing below code)

Tags: machine-learning

I have the implemented this code:

```
X_train=pd.DataFrame(preprocessor.fit_transform(X_train),columns=preprocessor.get_feature_names_out())
X_test=pd.DataFrame(preprocessor.transform(X_test),columns=preprocessor.get_feature_names_out())
```

If I run it I get the following error:
`'ColumnTransformer' object has no attribute 'get_feature_names_out`'

Comment: Probably you just have an older version of sklearn, from before the addition of `get_feature_names_out`.  Depending on how old it is, you might be able to use `get_feature_names` instead.